# Side by side multilevel MultiCells in FPDF

Tags: php, foreach, fpdf

I am in the process of converting 2 Cells into MultiCells for the purpose of text wrapping within FPDF.  I have followed a post on here which I found very useful to get the 2 MultiCells side by side.  The problem I have is that the MultiCell is within a foreach statement and it overlaps the next MultiCell if the previous MultiCell has multiple lines.  I have tried a couple of options so far including adding onto the height of the MultiCell but I need them to have appropriate height for the content within them.

Then I though well I need to work out the height of each MultiCell and add that too GetY.  I found the code for GetMultiCellHeight() but when trying to use this I remembered that this adds to the position of the current MultiCell and not the position of the NEXT MultiCell.  And this is where I got stuck!

This is the code I have so far:

```
foreach($final as $row){

// Only loop over the legal fee
if($row['fee_scale_category_id'] == 3){

    $amount_total += $row['amount'];
    $vat_total += $row['vat'];
    $total_total += ($row['amount'] + $row['vat']);
    $fee_amount = $row['amount'];



    $pdf->SetX(10);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();

    $multiCellHeight = $pdf->GetMultiCellHeight(80,6,$row['fee_scale_item'].':',0,"L"); 

    if ($multiCellHeight > 6) {

        $pdf->SetXY($x, $y + $multiCellHeight);

    } else {

        $pdf->SetXY($x, $y);

    }

    $pdf->MultiCell(80,6,$row['fee_scale_item'].':',0,"L");

    if ($multiCellHeight > 6) {

        $pdf->SetXY($x+ 80, $y + $multiCellHeight);

    } else {

        $pdf->SetXY($x + 80, $y);

    }

    $pdf->MultiCell(20,6,substr('Â£', 1, 1).round_me($row['amount'] + $row['vat']),0,"R");

}

}
```

Any help on how I can pass the height of the current MultiCell for use with the next MultiCell would be greatly appreciated!

Kind Regards,

n00bstacker

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the script [Table with MultiCells on fpdf.org](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php) is exactly what I need.  Thanks Oliver!